# .htaccess rewrite root domain to subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i am trying to forward all traffic to my subdomain via htaccess.

i am using that .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

its working but when i directly write my root domain to the address bar like: http://domain.com it stays on that url. i also want root domain to force forward to sub.domain.com

how to do that? help me out please.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make starting `www.` optional in `%{HOST_NAME}`.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```